# Syntax for object methods

Tags: javascript

I have always defined [methods in objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp) like this:

```
{
  a: function(par1, par2) { },
}
```

But recently I see this (which I assume is equivalent, but I am not sure):

```
{
  a(par1, par2) { },
}
```

When has this syntax been introduced?

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to is part of the [ES6 Extended Object Literal](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals) support.

You are correct in assuming that your two examples are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

It is ES6 syntax, a shorthand and functionally the same.

[MDN - Method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, 
this is new ES6 way of doing it

**old way**

```
var obj = {
  foo: function() {},
  bar: function() {}
};
```

**new way**

usually you can use old syntax, new one is optional but bit shorter

```
var obj = {
  foo() {},
  bar() {}
};
```

it better to skip duplication when you do something like that

```
function method(){};

return {
   method: method
};
```

it may looks like

```
return {
   method
};
```

same syntax you may find at es6 class definition

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(geometry, materials) {}
  update(camera) {}

  get boneCount() {}
  set matrixType(matrixType) {}
}
```

Best regards

Egor